# Is there any way to disable SSL for specific html element?

Tags: html, ssl, asp.net-mvc-5

We have Implemented SSL for our website which is in ASP.NET MVC 5 and it's working fine. But we have some Images from out side of our website and that can be with HTTP or HTTPS. And the pages where we have such images are treated as 'Not Secure' pages.
Is there any way to disable SSL for specific html element?

Comment: Change your image URLs from `http://` to `https://` and then your page will be fully labeled as "secure".

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, Image path come from third party and also those images are not available with https://

Comment: Then please edit your post as you seem to say the contrary: "we have some Images from out side of our website and that can be with HTTP or HTTPS"